# Sharing libraries via GIT

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git

In our company we've got a relatively small IT department. We use git to share our projects, and keep track of versions of them. Typical git usage. But now I've ran into an issue.

We've got a couple GIT repositories containing java projects. These projects are libraries. Some of the other projects use them. Right now, if I'd update a library, my co-workers would have to pull the GIT, open the project, export it to a .jar and include that in their projects. This is not how I want it. What I'd prefer to do is just add a library from a git. Like, tell the IDE (Either Android Studio or Eclipse) to just grab all files in that library from GIT.

What are my options?

Comment: "What are my options?" Well, use a dependency managament system. [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/), for example.

Comment: I agree with Seelenvirtuose, Maven or Gradle, with a continuous integration system like Jenkins, and an artifact repository. The setup may be tedious, but it worth it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me share my opinion.
GIT is first of all a source control tool.
So you don't need to 'store' jars (compiled libraries) in git. Ever :) This bloats the repository, and doesn't allow to process changes which aren't supposed to be binary.

Instead, in the scenario you've described, your colleague doesn't work with the library you're responsible for, so its a different project in git.

Depending on how your team/organizations is really small and whether your colleague and you are in really different projects there are a couple of options:

1. Keep all your jars in different modules of the same project (in the same git repository). Then use tools like maven or gradle to build your project. I don't know much about android developement, but I'm sure these tools have a lot to offer there.
   Both of them provide an automatic dependency management facility, so if you're responsible for module A and your teammate works with module B of the same project, just declare dependency 'B depends on A' (both maven and gradle allow this). 
   The overhead is obvious: you should compile everything every time you work with your code. Another drawback is that you have to follow the same release cycle for both A and B since they are parts of the same project.
   This setup is usually good for small organizations or even startups or if you really develop the library that is relevant only for your colleagues (in fact you're working on the same project).
2. Now in a more complicated environment, lets assume, that projects A and B are really different and developed by different people, maybe teams or departments.

In this case its better to keep A and B in different git repositories, allowing different release cycle and so forth.
You better still use maven or gradle but this time in conjunction with tools like Nexus or Artifactory. These are repositories for your artifacts (jars).

Since you obviously come from android world, the best analogy I can think of is 'google play' that stores all the products, but this time it keeps different versions, source code (optionally) or even javadoc if you wish so.

So now the flow should be like this:

You (as a maintainer of project A) compile it with maven or gradle, test and **deploy** to Nexus (or Artifactory). This means that there is some server where the jar is stored and there is an API for it that can be used by maven or gradle.

Now, your colleague has to decide on which version of project A he/she should rely in his build script. The maven should be configured to 'look for' artifacts in Nexus. In both maven and gradle its a couple of lines of configurations.

So in this case, your colleague works with his/her own git repository of project B, pulls the changes, and compiles (again with maven/gradle). Both of these build tools will 'download' the specified versions of project A.

On top of this you may consider to use continues integration tool like Jenkins, which will boost your productivity even further but its not directly related to your question.

Links:

[Maven](https://maven.apache.org/)

[Gradle](https://gradle.org/)

[Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/)

[Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/)

[Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using Android Studio but using eclipse, this is easy. First do. File->New Project->Android Application project

Yes says android application project but don't worry about it. Go through all steps but don't check 'create activity' and 'create launcher icon'

Now project will appear on left hand side. Right click, and make it an Android Library Project. Now copy your code and your `.git` into that new project's folder. Now you will have to do a few directory ogranizings.

Now the other users can import this as 'Android porject with existing source' and will not have to do all these steps agin.

In the projects that depends on this projects, you have to add it as a dependency library project.

Comment: We use both Android Studio and Eclipse. Just that the libraries are mostly made in eclipse, while the actual apps are made in Android Studio.

Comment: I think using both is very difficult. You can convert your library projects to android studio projects and import them as libraries there (more difficult to do than with eclipse but still can do). YOu can then manage the libraries with git and use the usual push/pull feature